# Connect a VM by LAN to a VM which has WAN

Tags: vmware-esxi, network-share

Using Esxi 6.7, I have two guests (Debian 10 on each one).
Guest-1 (VM-1) is configured with a public IP like this and is connected to WAN (internet) :

> sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo iface lo inet loopback


# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug ens192
iface ens192 inet static
    address xx.211.44.103/32
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway yy.27.36.113
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Vm-1 is connected to internet, no problem.
I need to configure a local network between machine Vm-1 and Vm-2, So let me know how to add a secondary internal IP `yy.27.36.151` to Vm-1 and a primary internal IP `yy.27.36.152` to Vm-2.

I tried this:
In Vm-1 :

```
# The secondary network interface
allow-hotplug ens193
iface ens193 inet static
     address yy.27.36.151
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway yy.27.36.113
     dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

And Vm-2 :

```
# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug ens193
iface ens193 inet static
     address yy.27.36.152
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway yy.27.36.113
     dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

The question is what should be secondary interface name ?? `ens193` and how to configure each machine?

```
sudo ifconfig -a
ens192: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet xx.211.44.103  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast xx.211.44.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:feca:ac60  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:ca:ac:60  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11155  bytes 765883 (747.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 12  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 18254  bytes 2084561 (1.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: You have to add another interface from ESXI first and connect it to another computer network via virtual network switch, preferrably other than WAN switch. If you wish to stay on simple network configuration you can add virtual interface on VM-1 with ifconfig ens192:1 command

Comment: Also your first VM has two default gateways, don't do that.

Comment: I'm trying to share Internet (WAN)  from Vm-1 to LAN (Vm-2), so I saw in this forum somewhere to use `public IP of Vm-1` as `gateway of LAN` . Any idea?